# ros2: C++ and Python in same package. Is it possible?

Tags: ros, python, ros2, c++, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

In ROS1, it was possible to have Python script in any package that contains C++ or Python, but in ROS2, it seems we need separate packages for Python and C++, which I do not find practical.

Is there any reason of not having the possibility to create one package for both C++ and Python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298740/ros2:-c++-and-python-in-same-package.-is-it-possible?/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2018-07-26

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-04-07**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/309391 is a follow-up to this question, as OP there didn't find none of the answers in this thread so far makes it clear how to mix C++ and Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to create a package having multiple programming languages. [rclpy](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/tree/bouncy/rclpy) is a ROS 2 package containing both python and C. The same could be done with C++ and python.

In ROS 1 using `catkin` and calling `catkin_python_setup()` in a `CMakeLists.txt` causes a `setup.py` file to be called, but the CMake code has to be there even if the package has no C or C++ code. In ROS 2 a package can be pure python.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-26**:
In ROS 2 a CMake project can install Python packages and modules (see https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/tree/7ab62a83055f7a14de9f2e65f60e166a99752eeb/ament_cmake_python/cmake) but it does provide a mechanism to invoke a `setup.py` file.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-26**:
While that could be implemented similar as it is in catkin it is fairly complex and the catkin implementation as several severe limitations. Therefore it hasn't been done until now.

**Comment by [lxbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/36253/lxbeyond/) on 2018-08-09**:
can we build demo_nodes_cpp and demo_nodes_py into one project as demo_nodes_test and run "ros2 run demo_nodes_test listener.py"(run python listener) or " ros2 run demo_nodes_test listener "(run c++ listener) ? I don't know how to install python executable with ament_cmake .

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2023-01-03**:
@Dirk Thomas Could you please provide an example in how to invoke a setup.py file in CMake?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can be done. I created a sample ROS2 pkg with .cpp and .py script in it, `setup.py` is not required in this case.  Here, the `CMakeLists.txt` needs to be slightly modified, and an empty `__init__.py` is used. You can refer to my sample code here:

https://github.com/tanyouliang95/MySandBox/tree/master/ros2_payload

---

Originally posted by [tanyouliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/39155/tanyouliang/) with karma: 61 on 2018-12-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ana de Sousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/55541/ana-de-sousa/) on 2020-06-08**:
I know that this is an old comment, but I am curious to know how do you execute PayloadController.py.
Thank you!

**Comment by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on 2020-10-29**:
`rosrun ros2_payload PayloadController.py`, see https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingServiceClient

**Comment by [Ana de Sousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/55541/ana-de-sousa/) on 2020-10-29**:
Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is by now easily possible.

You create an cpp package as usual and add the package structure of a normal python package.

The difference is, that you don't need the setup.cfg and setup.py files as this is now all handled by CMakeList.txt.

You have to make small adjustments as adding

```
find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)
find_package(rclpy REQUIRED)
```

and modify the package.xml to support building with python:

```
<buildtool_depend>ament_cmake_python</buildtool_depend>
```

For more detailed explanations please look at these ressources:

[ros2-package-for-both-python-and-cpp-nodes](https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-package-for-both-python-and-cpp-nodes/)

[creating-a-mixed-cpp-and-python-package](https://github.com/bponsler/ros2-support/blob/master/tutorials/creating-a-mixed-cpp-and-python-package.md)

In short your structure has to look like this:

```
my_example_package/
CMakeLists.txt
package.xml
include/
    my_example_package/
        some_file.hpp
src/
    some_file.cpp
my_example_package/
    __init__.py
    some_module.py
    another_module.py
scripts/
    my_executable
```

package.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>my_cpp_py_pkg</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="your@email.com">Name</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake_python</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>rclpy</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

and CMakeList.txt like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(my_cpp_py_pkg)
# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# Find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rclpy REQUIRED)

# Include Cpp "include" directory
include_directories(include)

# Create Cpp executable
add_executable(cpp_executable src/cpp_node.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(cpp_executable rclcpp)

# Install Cpp executables
install(TARGETS
  cpp_executable
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

# Install Python modules
ament_python_install_package(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Install Python executables
install(PROGRAMS
  scripts/py_node.py
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()
```

---

Originally posted by [Andreas Z](https://answers.ros.org/users/53868/andreas-z/) with karma: 171 on 2020-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5